# Is there any limitation or requirements for questions and issues about 3rd party apps?

Tags: discussion

Whenever I want to check out and answer a few questions about the Android OS, I'm always seeing questions like 'Can't connect to my Facebook account', 'Recover photos from Gallery Vault' and 'Twitter not posting tweets', which I have no idea at all about providing an answer. Among the 3rd party apps, WhatsApp takes the greatest prevalance. Most of those questions are not marked as off-topic (as they really aren't). In my opinion most should go to either their developer feedback hub or their special discussion forums, so why are so much allowed here?
P.S. I agree that it's OK for some of them to go here, like 'XXX app can't access external SD card' or 'XXX not producing sound'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, the site is for users of Android about using Android.  Using apps is inseparable from this.

I agree with you that a lot of these questions would do better in other places, and some of them — WhatsApp questions in particular, as you've noted — are borderline off-topic.  Generally speaking, we try to separate questions about how the service works ("Why can so-and-so still see my messages?") from questions using about the app ("How do I block someone?"), with the former being off-topic, but the line is blurry.  Especially with services that are only available on mobile.

I tend to want to see most of these questions gone, as you do, but in the past I have been part of the minority.